# how to view internal jaxws logs in tomcat

Tags: xml, soap, https, jax-ws, logging

I have a web service that is deployed in tomcat, and it is rejecting a soap request over https. However, I can't see any logs as to why it is doing so.

I have the following set in my service endpoint implementation file:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "all");
```

And I pass the following parameters to tomcat:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

Is there anything else I need to do to see the internal jaxws logs? Are there some other loggers I need to enable?

Answer (score 2):

There are other options to enable SOAP logging (depending on the used implementation) see:

http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_1_soap_messaging_logging

http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/message_logging_in_wsit_updated

However, are you sure the call reaches your service implementation?